# Canon speedlites not firing when in Live View

Tags: canon, hotshoe-flash, live-view, canon-5d-mark-iii

I am having difficulty getting my Canon speedlites (600ex master and two 430ex slaves) to fire when using Live View on my 5D Mark III.

I have no triggering problems except when using Live View. I was even able to get the speedlites to fire when using the EOS utility tethered to the camera. However, when I use Live View on the camera and trigger using the camera or a remote, no dice.

I have looked at other similar issues, but all seem to relate to non-Canon flash units. I tried setting Silent Mode to off for my case, but that made no difference.

Any ideas? I'd like to use Live View because I have an external monitor for people to view their photos prior to snapping the pic, in a photo booth setting.

Comment: Do you mean *photo booth* in the conventional sense (an enclosed space where light can bounce around) or in the more recent trend to call a self serve two light setup with a backdrop in an open area a *photo booth*?

Comment: Are you using Quick AF by any chance?  If so are you sure it is actually taking an image?  Sometimes Quick focus actuates the mirror but doesn't actually capture an image if it can't get focus.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change your live view AF mode setting. Try twiddling between the few settings that there are. Set your live view AF to quick I think and voila!

Answer (score 0):

If either of the *Silent Shooting* modes are enabled, flashes won't fire. With the camera in Live View, set the *Silent Shooting* setting to [Disable].